# Stencil CLI Installation Hiccup

Tags: bigcommerce

Ran into a small hiccup when attempting to install the stencil CLI on my machine running Ubuntu 14.04. I will attach the contents of the error below. At this point, I've been able to verify that npm, and node are installed correctly and I've been able to verify that I have the correct GitHub permissions by confirming my ability to access https://github.com/bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-cli. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
dante@Ubuntu:~$ sudo npm install -g bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-cli
[sudo] password for dante:
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-cli Cloning   into bare repository '/home/dante/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-bigcommerce-stencil-stencil-cli-12bc62b4'...  
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-cli Warning: Permanently added the RSA host   key for IP address '192.30.252.130' to the list of known hosts.  
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-cli Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-cli fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-cli
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-cli Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-cli and the repository exists.
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-cli
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, stat 'bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-cli'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR! http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR! npm-@googlegroups.com

npm ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-57-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-cli"
npm ERR! cwd /home/dante
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path bigcommerce-stencil/stencil-cli
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR! /home/dante/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I might also add that I've verified that npm is also installed on my machine as it is bundled w/ the node installation. I feel as if this is something that I'm easily overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the closed source code. You need to go through the early access dev flow and add your SSH keys, etc. Should resolve it.